# Passed Bitmap is Not Drawing on Another Activity

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to draw a Bitmap on a ImageView, but it is not showing... I created the Bitmap and stored on a Intent Extra, but on the new activity I'm not able to draw it on the ImageView.

Here is my code, calling the new activity:

```
public void onClickShare(View v) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Share.class);

        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        myIntent.putExtra("createdImg", b);
        startActivity(myIntent);

    }
```

And on the new activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.share);

        backgroundImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        Intent myIntent = getIntent();      
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) myIntent.getParcelableExtra("createdImg");

        backgroundImg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: try to load a bitmap from resource and not an empty one check ur results

Comment: @PulkitSethi, it worked, I converted a drawable to a bitmap and worked. I changed this "Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);" to this "Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cor1);". So maybe it is the createBitmap the problem?

Comment: may be the problem was the empty bitmap, and how imageview shows images and resizes based on the contents of the image pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took it a little bit from every answer, plus other researches, and I came up with the code below that worked nicely:

Calling the new activity:

```
public void onClickShare(View v) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Share.class); 

        // create bitmap screen capture
        Bitmap bitmap;
        View v1 = v.getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());

        // create a new one with the area I want
        Bitmap bmpLast = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 25, 185, 430, 520);        
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        //create an empty bitmap with the size I need
        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 760, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        //draw the content on the bitmap
        Canvas c = new Canvas(bmOverlay); 
        c.drawBitmap(bmpLast, 0, 0, null);

        //compress the bitmap to send to other activity
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmpLast.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();    

        //store compressed bitmap 
        myIntent.putExtra("createdImg", byteArray);     

        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

And on the new activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.share);

    //decompress the bitmap
    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("createdImg");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

    //set the imageview with the bitmap
    backgroundImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    backgroundImg.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp));
}
```

Thanks everyone! =)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send it as ByteArray and decode it in the receiving activity.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

Intent in1 = new Intent(this, Share.class);
in1.putExtra("image",byteArray);
```

in the second activity

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("image");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("createdImg", b);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and in next activity

```
Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
Bitmap bmap = bundle.getParcelable("createdImg");
```

as given in this tutorial http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/pass-bitmap-between-activities.html